# How to understand and change CPU register FLAG in bochsdbg?

Tags: cpu-registers, bochs

I can use 'r' to get the info of CPU register FLAG.

1.Can I understand by this?

```
  eflags 0x00000082: id vip vif ac vm rf nt IOPL=0 of df if tf SF zf af pf cf
  0x00000082=        0   0   0  0  0  0   0   0    0  0  1  0  1  0  0  1  0
```

2.How to change the FLAG? By 'set' command?

```
   <bochs:5> set eflags=0x03
   :5: syntax error at 'eflags'
```

Thank you~

Comment: Very very late reply. But I thought I add my bit. As @vadim-k pointed out that capital names means that the flag is set, but does not answer why 0x82 not align with the flags. This is because there are reserved bits in EFLAGS which are not displayed - for example the bit-1, 3, 5 are reserved. Also bit-1 is reserved but always need to set to 1.

Answer (score 4):

1. If the flag name is in capitals, then the flag is set. E.g. 'SF' means that sign flag is set, while 'sf' means it is not set. Did you mean this, or something else in your question?
2. The bochs manual says: "Currently only general purpose registers are supported, you may not change: eflags, eip, cs, ss, ds, es, fs, gs" (http://bochs.sourceforge.net/doc/docbook/user/internal-debugger.html#AEN3098).

Regards